# Qt, QUrl, QUrlQuery: Encoding special character in a query string

Tags: qt, encoding, query-string, urlencode, urldecode

I create a URL query like this:

```
QString normalize(QString text)    
{    
    text.replace("%", "%25");    
    text.replace("@", "%40");    
    text.replace("‘", "%27");    
    text.replace("&", "%26");    
    text.replace("“", "%22");    
    text.replace("’", "%27");    
    text.replace(",", "%2C");    
    text.replace(" ", "%20");    

    return text;    
}    
QString key = "usermail";
QString value = "aemail@gmail.com";    
QUrlQuery qurlqr;    
qurlqr.addQueryItem(normalize(key), normalize(value));

QString result = qurlqr.toString();
```

The result that's be expecting is :

```
usermail=aemail%40gmail.com.
```

But I received:

```
usermail=aemail@gmail.com
```

I don't know why. Can you help me?

(I'm using Qt5 on Win7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QUrlQuery's toString by default decodes the percent encoding.  If you want the encoded version try:

`qurlqr.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded)`

Also you don't need to manually encode the string by replacing characters; you could instead use `QUrl::toEncoded()` (I suggest you read the [QUrlQuery](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qurlquery.html) documentation).

Comment: Be careful however, toEncoded will not work with '+' signs.